# ZMQContext сбрасывает соединение в браузере

Tags: windows, php7, ratchet, zmq

Пишу вебсокет-сервер на Ratchet. Всё настроил пользователи подключаются по ws://localhost:8080. Единственной проблемой осталось то что не получается отправить свои данные с помощью ZMQContext. Делаю всё как в документации (http://socketo.me/docs/push). Привожу код ниже:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher'); 
//На этом моменте соединение разрывается браузер выдает ERR_CONNECTION_RESET   
$socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
$socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
```

Причем запуская этот же код через консоль - всё работает. Это наводит на мысль что или Apache не дружит с этой библиотекой, либо ее вообще противопоказано запускать с браузера. Но мне нужно на продакшене, чтоб вебсервер отправлял данные вебсокет-серверу. Это будет происходить через браузер, консолью тут не обойтись. В чем может быть причина?

В документации написано, что ZMQContext::getSocket в случае ошибки выбрасывает исключение ZMQSocketException. Но даже обернув весь этот код в

```
try...catch(ZMQSocketException $exception){...}
```

не помогает. Браузер возвращает разорванное соединение либо ошибку 502.

P.S. Веб-сервер - Apache, OC - Windows 10, PHP 7.2, расширение zmq для php установлено